# Json_normalize applied to a Pandas Series returns '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a function that returns a flattened `series` from a `Pandas Series` using `json_normalize`.

```
def extract(self, mydf,field_name):
    return json_normalize(mydf[field_name])
```

It returns: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

I verified and `mydf[field_name]` works and I am able to get to the series value, so is not something related with the Dataframe.

Example of my json (Series row):

```
'{\'myfield\': \'XXXX\', \'fieldA\': \'ValueA\'}'
```

I have found related issues about the error log but nothing related using `json_normalize`.

The whole values in the series:

```
0 = {str} '{\'my_type\': \'Earn\', \'r\': {\'a\': \'275\', \'t\': \'F\'}}'
1 = {str} '{\'my_type\': \'Log\', \'m\': \'first\'}'
2 = {str} '{\'my_type\': \'Earn\', \'r\': {\'a\': \'3\', \'t\': \'Ess\'}}'
3 = {str} '{\'my_type\': \'Earn\', \'r\': {\'a\': \'20\', \'t\': \'E\'}}'
4 = {str} '{\'my_type\': \'Match\', \'d\': \'5\', \'t\': \'p\', \'name\': \'3-3\'}'
```

Comment: Can you please share your sample code and sample dataframe?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your JSON?

Comment: @NYCCoder json example and function are already in the question

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your JSON looks like the one below:

```
[
    {
        "my_type": "Earn",
        "r": {
            "a": "275",
            "t": "F"
        }
    },
    {
        "my_type": "Log",
        "m": "first"
    },
    {
        "my_type": "Earn",
        "r": {
            "a": "3",
            "t": "Ess"
        }
    },
    {
        "my_type": "Earn",
        "r": {
            "a": "20",
            "t": "E"
        }
    },
    {
        "my_type": "Match",
        "d": "5",
        "t": "p",
        "name": "3-3"
    }
]
```

Python code to convert it to DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('1.json', 'r+') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df)

  my_type  r.a  r.t      m    d    t name
0    Earn  275    F    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1     Log  NaN  NaN  first  NaN  NaN  NaN
2    Earn    3  Ess    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3    Earn   20    E    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   Match  NaN  NaN    NaN    5    p  3-3
```

Comment: Just add all series